# Rails, ActionController::UnknownFormat when testing a post (create) request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am testing my rails application and so far this test is failing all the others pass.

The test is as follows:

```
  test "should create broadcast" do
    assert_difference('Broadcast.count') do
      post :create, broadcast: { title: "title", content: "content", user_id: @broadcast.user_id}
    end

    assert_redirected_to broadcast_path(assigns(:broadcast))
  end
```

and the controller has this snippet:

```
 feed_result = []
    if params.has_key?(:feeds)
      feed_result = params[:feeds]
    else
      feed_result = ["None"]
    end


if @broadcast.save

        # Only after saving do we try and do the real broadcast. Could have been
        # done using an observer, but I wanted this to be more explicit

        results = BroadcastService.broadcast(@broadcast, feed_result)
        if results.length > 0
          # Something went wrong when trying to broadcast to one or more of the
          # feeds.
          @broadcast.errors[:base] << ("#{I18n.t('broadcasts.unable-message')}: #{results.inspect}")
          flash[:error] = I18n.t('broadcasts.saved-but-message')
        else
          flash[:notice] = I18n.t('broadcasts.saved-message')
          no_errors = true
        end
        if no_errors
          format.html { redirect_to(broadcasts_url(page: @current_page)) }
          format.json { render json: @broadcast, status: :created, location: @broadcast }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.xml {
            # Either say it partly worked but send back the errors or else send
            # back complete failure indicator (couldn't even save)
            if results
              render json: @broadcast.errors, status: :created, location: @broadcast
            else
              render json: @broadcast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
          }
        end
      end
    end
```

I have left out information that is unnecessary. it must be noted that if i am not running a test, and i am in fact running the live server this create method functions as expected and no error is thrown.

i have tried the following:

```
 post :create, broadcast: { title: "title", content: "content", user_id: @broadcast.user_id, format: :html}

 post :create, broadcast: { title: "title", content: "content", user_id: @broadcast.user_id, format: :json}


 post :create, broadcast: { title: "title", content: "content", user_id: @broadcast.user_id, format: 'html'}

 post :create, broadcast: { title: "title", content: "content", user_id: @broadcast.user_id, format: 'json'}
```

And the error persists.

If anyone has any ideas, id love to hear them!

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Does `params[:feeds]` end up `nil` b/c you're not supplying a value? Does that affect behavior?

Comment: i don't think so i have this error check to see,   feed_result = []
    if params.has_key?(:feeds)
      feed_result = params[:feeds]
    else
      feed_result = ["None"]
    end

    puts "#{feed_result.inspect}" and that is printing ["None"]

Comment: Were you able to make it work? Did you try this: post :create, broadcast: { title: "title", content: "content", user_id: @broadcast.user_id}, :format => 'json'